# Function integration of a Gaussian integral - examination of assumptions

Tags: operators, path-integral, partition-function

Consider the partition function $Z[J]$ of the Klein-Gordon theory

$$Z[J] =\int \mathcal{D}\phi\ e^{i\int d^{4}x\ [\frac{1}{2}(\partial\phi)^{2}-\frac{1}{2}m^{2}\phi^{2}+J\phi]}
            =\int \mathcal{D}\phi\ e^{-i\int d^{4}x\ [\frac{1}{2}\phi(\partial^{2}+m^{2})\phi]}\ e^{i\int d^{4}x\ J\phi}
$$
    If the operator $\partial^{2}+m^{2}$ is symmetric and positive-definite, then

$$Z[J]=\int \mathcal{D}\phi\ e^{i\int d^{4}x\ [\frac{1}{2}\phi(-\partial^{2}-m^{2})\phi]}\ e^{-\frac{i}{2}\int d^{4}x\ J(-\partial^{2}-m^{2})^{-1}J(x)}.$$

---

The assumption of symmetry and positive-definiteness of the operator $\partial^{2}+m^{2}$ is crucial in the derivation of the Feynman diagrammatic rules of the scalar theory from the partition function of the scalar theory.

What does it mean for an operator to be symmetric and positive-definite? Is the operator $\partial^{2}+m^{2}$ symmetric and positive-definite?

Does the operator $(\partial^{2}+m^{2})$ have to be symmetric and positive-definite in order for its inverse $(\partial^{2}+m^{2})^{-1}$ to exist?

If the operator $\partial^{2}+m^{2}$ is symmetric and positive-definite, then is the operator $(\partial^{2}+m^{2})^{-1}$ also symmetric and positive-definite?

What set of conditions must the operator $(\partial^{2}+m^{2})^{-1}$ satisfy in order for $(-\partial^{2}-m^{2})^{-1}=-(\partial^{2}+m^{2})^{-1}$?

Comment: The partition function is defined in the Euclidean path integral formalism. In your case, since a factor $i $ appears in the exponent, the formalism is Lorentzian instead. $\partial^2 + m^2$ is not symmetric in the Lorentzian formalism because there is no Hilbert scalar product notion. If the formalism is Euclidean, the operator is symmetric (essentially self-adjoint) but it is not positive-definite.

Comment: You mention that the partition function is defined in the Euclidean path integral formalism.  Does my second equation therefore not follow from my first equation? You mention that $\partial^{2}+m^{2}$ is not symmetric in the Lorentzian formalism because there is no Hilbert scalar product notion. But do we not talk about the norm of Lorentz four-vectors - does this not imply the existence of Hilbert scalar product notion in the Lorentzian formalism?

Comment: You also mention that 'if the formalism is Euclidean, the operator is symmetric (essentially self-adjoint) but it is not positive-definite'. But according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#n-dimensional_with_linear_term the operator $A$ must be both symmetric and positive-definite in order for the integration to proceed!

Comment: Regarding your first reply, you are confonding the notion of Hilbert space scalar product and the notion of Lorentzian scalar product of vectors in spacetime. Concerning the second one, the formally self adjoint operator $\delta^{ab}\partial_a\partial_b + m^2I$ acting on smooth compactly-supported functions  is not positive-definute, the proof is elementary. The relevant operator in the definition of the partition function has a further minus sign un front of the Laplacian, $-\delta^{ab}\partial_a\partial_b + m^2I$ and is positive-definite.

Comment: Your second equation does not follow from the first one unless you declare the meaning of the inverse operator appearing in the second exponent, since the initial operator does not admit a unique inverse. Usually the used inverse here is the Feynman propagator. If the formalism were Eucludean, the inverse would be unique as you correctly state, for a positive definite operator...

Comment: Reagarding your first sentence, are symmetric operators not defined in the Lorentzian formalism? Also, is my linked formula for Gaussian integrals defined in the Euclidean formalism and not in the Lorentzian formalism?

Comment: Yes the notion is not well defined in Lorentzian formalism since there is not a Hilbert space scalar product. The linked formula refers to the Euclidean formalism, in fact  no factors i appear.